# Checkbox limiter prompts user to increase selection increment

Tags: javascript, html

I have a a form that allows users to select only 3 boxes. However, I would like a prompt to come up when the user selects the fourth box asking if they would like to increase their selections and if they choose yes, the number of boxes they are allowed to check will increase to 5.
This is for a list of products I am selling.

Anyone have any idea how to do this. Here is my sample code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* Limit number of checked checkboxes script- by JavaScript Kit (www.javascriptkit.com)
* This notice must stay intact for usage
* Visit JavaScript Kit at http://www.javascriptkit.com/ for this script and 100s more
***********************************************/

function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit){
    var checkgroup=checkgroup
    var limit=limit
    for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++){
        checkgroup[i].onclick=function(){
        var checkedcount=0
        for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++)
            checkedcount+=(checkgroup[i].checked)? 1 : 0
        if (checkedcount>limit){
            alert("Your box is full.")
            this.checked=false
            }
        }
    }
}

</script>

<p>Select your favorite two countries below:</p>

<form id="world" name="world">
<input type="checkbox" name="countries" /> USA<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="countries" /> Canada<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="countries" /> Japan<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="countries" /> China<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="countries" /> France<br />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

//Syntax: checkboxlimit(checkbox_reference, limit)
checkboxlimit(document.forms.world.countries, 2)

</script>
```

Comment: dose it have to be the first three or can they check any of the three in any/random order?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit){

   var v_checkgroup = checkgroup;
   var v_limit = limit;

  for (var i=0; i < v_checkgroup.length; i++){

    v_checkgroup[i].onclick= function(){

    var checkedcount = 0;

    for (var i=0; i < v_checkgroup.length; i++)

    checkedcount += (v_checkgroup[i].checked)? 1 : 0

    if (checkedcount > v_limit){
    var confirmIncrease = confirm("would like to increase you selection\r\nSelect yes to increase or\r\nCancle to remove");
    if(confirmIncrease){        

    // manualy set the limit
           //  v_limit = 5; 
           // set the limit based on number of checkboxs
    v_limit = checkgroup.length; // rase the limit to the remaining


    }else{ // uncheck if they dont wish to increase the limit 
    //alert("no worries")
    this.checked=false
    }
    } }
 }
}
```

let me know if it works as you wanted

Comment: No that didn't work. I have decided to go with an easier method, however, if anyone wants to take a crack at this, feel free! It's a good challenge!